# Reload chef recipes if install fails or updates are available

Tags: chef-infra

This is a super basic task, but I can't find documentation on it. I am booting EC2 machines using a chef-server and chef. If that fails i would like to fix the recipes and then reinstall the role and recipes on that machine without taking the node out and creating it again. I cannot find the command that does that.

If I run chef-client on the machine I get:

```
chef-client
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:58 +0000] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.0 ***
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] INFO: Run List is []
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] INFO: Run List expands to []
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] INFO: Starting Chef Run for gidsy-staging-web
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] INFO: Loading cookbooks []
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] WARN: Node gidsy-staging-web has an empty run list.
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.508629 seconds
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] INFO: Running report handlers
[Wed, 18 Jan 2012 11:23:59 +0000] INFO: Report handlers complete
```

Thanks

Comment: Your problem description isn't very clear, between EC2 and Chef there is some terminology overlap. It is unclear what you mean by "without taking the node out and creating it again" (chef node or EC2 node?)
What is the output of your failed run?
Why is your Run List empty? I've not seen an occasion where a failed Chef run would empty the run list of a node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue and this is how I have resolved the issue.

First, I apply the role(s) in question to the instance using knife:

```
$ knife node run_list add [NODE] [ENTRY]

Be sure and include the items in [ENTRY] in quotes (for example, "role[my-role]").
```

Once the role has been applied to the EC2 instance, I then invoke chef-client on the instance in question.

```
$ sudo chef-client
```

This should speed up your development cycle substantially.

Answer (score 2):

Jordan's answer really helped me out but for those who are starting chef like me I will explain in a bit more detail.

I am running on EC2 and was getting the above error. This is what I did to resolve it:

1. On my local machine, run: `knife ec2 server list` to get the host node on the EC2 server
2. Add the run list to that node from my local dev machine: `knife node run_list add i-xxxxx  "role[aws-db-deploy]"` where i-xxxxx  is your node name
3. ssh onto your aws ec2 instance and run the command: `sudo chef-client`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can run the chef-client with the runlist:

```
$ sudo chef-client --runlist <role>
```